# operend type do not match & illegal instruction

Tags: assembly

there is an error in line 20 
that can't mov edx,dx and other error in line 30 " the function name "

can someone help me ?
note :: .startup in my code mean 
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

```
.model small,c
.486
.stack 200h
.data 
    num DW ?


    arr db "Plese enter a Number$"
.code
    rev proc _TT:word
    uses ebx,eax,cx
    LOCALS
    mov EBX,0
    mov cx ,0
    mov Ax,_TT
again: CWD
    div cx
    imul  EBX,10
    movs edx,dx  ; <=== error here
    push EAX
    mov ax,dx
    cwde
    add ebx,eax
    pop eax
    cmp eax,0
    JG again
    ret
    endp
    rav
.startup

    .exit
    end
```

Comment: Did you mean `MOVSX` (sign-extended)?

Comment: yes that what i mean thx :)

Comment: the code have another error after ret

Comment: `rev endp`, not `endp` linebreak `rav`.

Comment: oooooh  that a small error

Comment: thx i fixed it but when i run the code 
it print this message  "divide overflow"

Comment: Get a book on x86 assembly and start reading my friend.

Comment: People, let's play by the rules. Michael - write an answer. Mohammad - accept the answer and ask a new question. And before asking, try debugging the error yourself. SO should never be your **first** source of information.

Answer (score 1):

These are the offending lines related to your original question, and their correct replacements:

```
movs edx,dx  ; <=== error here
```

Replace with:

```
movsx edx,dx  ; Sign-extend dx into edx
```

`endp`
    `rav`

Replace with:

`rev endp   ; the end of  "rev proc"`