# Assembly MOVS instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

Am a beginner in the Assembly Language.. and I have a question on this piece of code.. It just keeps giving me this error - on the code - Isn't .. :? This function should reverse a number

```
    rev proc _x:word
uses EAX, EDX, EBX, ECX
LOCALS
MOV EBX, 0
MOV Cx,10
MOV AX, _x
CWD
DIV CX
iMUL EBX,10
MOVS EDX,DX ; error Operand types do not match.. 
push EAX
MOV AX, DX
Again:CWDE
Add EBX, EAX
POP EAX
cmp EAX, 0
JA again
ret
endp rev
```

Comment: Are you trying to zero-extend `DX` into `EDX`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [operend type do not match & illegal instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621590/operend-type-do-not-match-illegal-instruction)

Comment: It should be signed.. Isn't zero-extending just for positive values :?

Comment: Just to clarify: Zero-extending is for unsigned values. Sign-extending works for both positive and negative (signed) values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembler is probably thinking that you want the `MOVSB/MOVSW/MOVSD` instruction. Its operands (implicit) are indeed of the same size.

Write `MOVSX` instead of `MOVS`.